# Could metal rods conduct geothermal energy to the surface?

Tags: thermodynamics, earth, thermal-conductivity

Currently geothermal heat pumps circulate a working fluid through a loop running in either a deep well or a long series of more shallow trenches.  Boring a well is expensive and digging trenches chews up a large chunk of land.

Could an array of metal rods (rebar connected to a sacrificial anode?) driven into the ground effectively conduct heat to a heat-exchanger at the surface? Would this cost less than the other methods?

Comment: If you thermally isolated the rebar you might be OK. I will note that steel is a lousy heat conductor. Then you have to get the heat into a working fluid anyway.

Comment: A heat pipe would be more efficient than a solid metal bar.

Answer (score 6):

Since the characteristic time of diffusion is L²/D, where L is the characteristic length and D is the diffusivity (here, the [thermal diffusivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_diffusivity)), the characteristic speed is D/L, or 10<sup>-7</sup> m/s for a 1 km deep probe and very thermally conductive copper. We can pump liquid far faster than this.

Looking at the conductive power delivery, we have kAΔT/L for the probe, where k is the thermal conductivity, A is the cross-sectional area and ΔT is the temperature difference. Compare this to ρCVΔT/t for advective transfer, where ρ is the material density, C is its specific heat capacity, V is its volume, and t is the turnaround time. Dividing by AΔT, we’re comparing the magnitudes of k/L and ρCv, where v is the liquid pumping speed. We find again that v need only exceed 10<sup>-7</sup> m/s for water to best a strongly conductive rod.

The conclusion is that when L is large (or even longer than millimeters), pumping liquid is generally a far more effective way to transfer thermal energy than to rely on conduction.

(I’ll leave it to you to incorporate the relevant cost comparison, which takes this topic into engineering.)

Comment: Could you pump the liquid without using any external power sources, though? Since with a metal rod, you could just leave it there and it would transfer heat without need for any further energy input.

Comment: [Natural convection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_convection) would circulate the liquid without requiring power if any temperature difference exists.